# Nested Async calls with Top level function doing await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, c#-5.0

I've this scenario, wanted to check if is feasible before going that route.

I've a webApi project, there is a delegateHandler which adds some data in HttpContext.Current.Items. In controller there are few async calls which I'm doing with configureawait(false). Same in the library DLL.

Overall code looks like this.....

**In controller**

```
public async Task<Entity> func()
{

HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(key, value);

await DBCalls.Method1Async().configureawait(false);
await DBCalls.Method2Async().configureawait(false);

var data = HttpContext.Current.Items[key];

// rest of the method
}
```

**In DLL, class DBCalls**

```
async void Method1Async()
{
   await internalMethod1().configureawait(false)
}
async void Method2Async()
{
   await internalMethod2().configureawait(false)
}
```

Question is when execution resumes back on controller function will I get stored data back from HttpContext.Current.Items?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427675/correct-way-to-use-httpcontext-current-user-with-async-await) should generally answer your question.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov Does it mean in controller if I modify code to Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).configureawait(true);  It should reenter request context

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When execution resumes back on controller function will I get stored data back from `HttpContext.Current.Items`?

No, you won't. `ConfigureAwait(false)` is exactly for the case when you *don't* need to resume on the previous context. But to access `HttpContext.Current`, you need that.

What you should do is to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in "library" code (like `InternalMethodN` and possibly `Method1Async`), which does not depend on the context. But in your "application" code, which needs to return to the ASP.NET request context, don't use `ConfigureAwait()`.

So, your code should look like this:

```
public async Task<Entity> Func()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(key, value);

    await DBCalls.Method1Async();
    await DBCalls.Method2Async();

    var data = HttpContext.Current.Items[key];

    // rest of the method
}

async Task Method1Async()
{
   await InternalMethod1().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

async Task Method2Async()
{
   await InternalMethod2().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Note that I have changed `MethodNAsync` from `async void` to `async Task`. You shouldn't use `async void` methods unless you have to and you certainly wouldn't be able to `await` them.

Also, I'm assuming that the real `MethodNAsync` actually do something. If they just delegate to the internal methods, you could simplify them to just (using C# 6.0 expression-bodied methods to make them even shorter):

```
Task Method1Async() => InternalMethod1();

Task Method2Async() => InternalMethod2();
```

Comment: In your last snippet those methods shouldn't be `async`, given your refactor.