# How to call a method as async without losing httpcontext

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, async-await, task

How to call a method as "async" without losing httpcontext and service context?
I am calling it inside a function that is not async .

Comment: Did u check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28433417/8063119).